# hot to access windows mobile SqlCE database from desktop vb.net

Tags: sql, windows, vb.net, mobile

I want to access the Windows mobile SQLCE database from the desktop application when device is connected to my PC. please suggest is it possible? how i do this?

Using .NET

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not supported: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/824909fc-783e-476a-8750-a05d8510b66d/